# Stick 2 btRigidBodies together

Tags: ogre, platformer, bullet-physics

I have a platform with btBoxShape as shape, and I want to rotate it every certain amount of time to simulate a rotating platform.

Right now I rotate it with Ogre (my rendering engine) and use a custom btMotionState to synchronize it with bullet. The thing is that when a player goes on top of it (a player is a btRigidBody with mass 1) the body should stay in the same coordinate relative to the platform and rotate with it. Right now it is kinda bugged and it doesn't rotate properly, and I don't know the exact cause.

What should I do to achieve this effect?

Here is a video with an example of what I want to do: http://youtu.be/z60jiGldX48?t=1m2s

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean "on_ground" variable to keep track of if your player is standing, or in midair. Ray cast underneath the player just like you would to see if it is OK to jump.

If your player->on_ground is false, and the ray hits something to stand on, make this object your new "platform" and set player->on_ground to true. Save the *local* (not world) coordinate where the ray hit as your "platform_offset". You can get this by taking the world space position where the ray hit, and transforming it by the *inverse* of the platform's model matrix.

Otherwise, if player->on_ground is true, then you just transform the platform_offset by the platform's model matrix. Move the player with it artificially if the platform has moved.